# Weird behaviour of direction property in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, right-to-left, direction

I was just playing around with CSS on Codepen with **auto-save mode enabled** when I encountered this weird behaviour,

Here's my code-

```js
var inner_div = document.querySelector('.inner-div');
var width = inner_div.offsetWidth;
if(width > 200)
  {
    inner_div.style.fontSize = '20px';
  }
```

```css
.outer-div {
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5em;
    width: 10%;
    border: 2px solid #000000a3;
    margin-left: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    direction: rtl;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.inner-div {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer-div">
    <div class = "inner-div">
       Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As my auto-save mode was enabled, I was checking with each key press whether the text is being appended from right to left or not, but **when I press slash(/), or any of the arithmetic operators(+, -, *), then these are first appended on the left first and then if the next keypress is alphanumeric then it appends it automatically to the right of the expression.**
*For e.g., if I type c, then b, then a, then it gets displayed as 'abc'(as desired from `direction: rtl` property), but if I then type slash(/), then the display is /abc, and then if I type any alphanumeric character, say d, then it displays abc/d .*
Could someone explain me the reason for this. Thanks.

Comment: read more about rtl direction and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Slash has BiDi (bi-directional) class on I think. The same thing with ! and other special character. It applies the direction in context of surrounding text

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the behavior you describe. The `direction` tag alone will not change the way

```
abc
```

is displayed. You were not typing **`c`**, then **`b`** and **`a`**.

The behavior you described happens when you type **`a`**, **`b`**, and, finally, **`c`**. If you type RTL characters, e.g. **`#x0627;&#x0628;&#x0629;`** - you will see **`ا ب ة`** appear from right to left. Note that this will work as well if you don't specify rtl direction. Also, the slash will appear on the left - no matter how you choose the direction.

You can achieve interesting effects if you add the [unicode-bidi](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_unicode-bidi.asp) tag to your CSS.